# Suspend resume works, but unable to use computer

Tags: suspend, pm-utils

When I suspend and resume from suspend, I see my screen as it was left but cannot use it and Caps Lock does not work.

When I run `pm-suspend` before loading X11, I am able to see my last command and to type onto the screen and make new lines, but I am not given the next line with which to enter commands.

I would prefer to get some directions as to how I can debug this (as likely no one knows this system precisely). Nevertheless, I am using a Mac Mini Server 2012 with Intel HD Graphics 3000 and Ubuntu 13.04 kernel version 10.x and I just recently installed the Intel Graphics drivers (I used to have only a blank screen on resume).

Answer (score 0):

Could you see if this same thing happens if you run this for suspend?

```
sudo echo mem > /sys/power/state
```

Comment: I have thought about the issue and I think that the problem is that I am booting from a thunderbolt drive. When I have time, I will try  moving the hard drive internal. What is the purpose / effect of that command?